# How to improve rendering performance with multiple equal and heavy movieclips?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, air

I have 25 kind of heavy movieclips on the screen. They show many bitmaps, each one of in one of their frames. The problem is that the application gets unusable when they are on screen. And even after removing them the app keeps slow.

Using Adobe Air 2.0, compiled by Flash CS5.

Answer (score 0):

There literally thousands of optimization tricks for Flash, but one that usually helps when dealing with large (or complex) Sprites or MovieClips is the [cacheAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#cacheAsBitmap) property:

```
my_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

And since you are using Adobe Air, you can also have access to the [cacheAsBitmapMatrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#cacheAsBitmapMatrix) property, for further optimization (badly needed on mobile devices!):

```
my_mc.cacheAsBitmapMatrix= my_mc.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
my_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true; //also this!
```

Check out this [Republic of Code tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3cacheasbitmap/) about when/why better use them.
Hope this helps!

Comment: they are actually animated, cacheAsBitmap wouldn't help.